# C++ function returning different types

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a function where based on the parameter the function returns the value, like this:

```
type getValue(string input) return <OUTPUT>
```

`OUTPUT`'s type would be changed to `int`, `string`, `bool`, etc., on what the input is given. I got that sorted but the problem that I've been having is the return type. I've tried `auto` type but all I got was this error:

> error: inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'int' and then 'char'

over and over again with every single types that this function can output. I wouldn't do templates because you have to do this

```
getValue<type>(input);
```

and I have no way to just guessing to output to put in the template type. I've used so many options that I can do but it was just way too complicated.

Comment: Use [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) as return type.

Comment: Or [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: If the return type is identical to that of argument, you can use a template just fine, typing `getValue(input)` is enough and the compiler can guess what type you want to use

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes The way I understood the question, the argument is always a std::string, and the return type depends on the content of the string.

Comment: why would you want to get dynamic type in a statically typed language? Even though it can be achieved, most of the time it's the wrong approach from people using dynamically typed languages

Comment: Avoid `std::any` or `std::variant`, they are advanced stuff. Get familiar with the basics first. Answer this question: what do you do with the return value if you don't know what type it is?

Comment: `union` is what you need. `std::variant` if you work with c++17.

Comment: @Yves union doesn't work if the type is non-POD

Comment: @phuclv You are right, so I guess `boost::variant` is the only choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, you'll need to use a `std::variant` or `std::any` as a return type.

```
std::any getValue(string input) {
    if (input == ...) {
        return "string return type";
    }
    if (input == ...) {
        return 100;
    }
    if (input == ...) {
        return 123.456;
    }

    return false;
}
```

However if there are only a small set of return types you could produce, consider using a variant as it's a bit more constrained:

```
// assuming these are the only 4 types you can return
using getValueReturnType = std::variant<std::string, int, double, bool>;

// The function definition would be exactly the same as above with std::any
getValueReturnType getValue(string input);
```

Comment: The literal in the third return statement is a double, not a float.